# Cannot Compile SafeMoon Contract On Remix Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

Im trying to Compile SafeMoon Contract and its giving me Warning

> Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before
> publishing, consider adding a comment containing
> "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use
> "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please
> see https://spdx.org for more information.

And

> Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version!
> Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.6.12;"

Actually Im writing a Contract in which I have to Interact with UNISwap Interface and Router. When ever I add Interface of Uniswap Router It gives this warning and fails to Compile. Any Tips to Compile

link of SafeMoon Contract is
https://github.com/safemoonprotocol/Safemoon.sol/blob/main/Safemoon.sol

Answer (score 1):

After some research Found the Answer. Nothing was wrong with the Code. Remix has a limit of contracts it can Store. After Removing some of the Contracts I was able to Compile it.